# How do I selectively turn off template caching in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, caching

I am sending emails in a background job using ActionMailer.  Users can create new email templates but they aren't recognized until the background job is restarted.  Used to use

```
ActionView::TemplateFinder.reload!
```

which forced reloading of templates (now deprecated on 2.3.4).  I have tried

```
ActionView::Base.cache_template_loading = false
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

What I wound up doing was setting a global variable in my background process before the Rails environment was loaded:

```
$background = true
```

then in environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_view.cache_template_loading = !$background
```

Not thrilled, but it works.  I get template reloading for email templates in my background job but cached view templates for the online application.

Answer (score 0):

Since your users can create (and possibly change) templates, why don't you store them on the database and render as inline erb?

```
render :inline => template_record.contents
```

Now that I suggested this, I noticed... You can also use `:inline` to manually read the template and pass it to ActionView. You'll have to handle the exceptional case of the template not existing, though.

```
render :inline => File.read( ... )
```

Comment: I'm building up content with render_message which only take template_path and hash of substitution variables.

Comment: The mailing code is much better in Rails 3.0, have you considered upgrading?

Comment: Looking forward to 3.0 but not an option for this app right now.